# swift) In the for loop, even iterating the last index, referencing .index(after: index) does not make an error ? why?

Tags: swift

```
var a = "hi my name is Jim."

for index in a.indices {
    var rightAfterIndex = a.index(after: index)
}
```

In the code above, at the end of the for-loop, I will definitely be iterating the last index of the swift String, but still, referencing the index after the last index does not make an error.
Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index after the last item of `indices` is the (valid) `endIndex` of the string.

```
a.index(after: a.indices.last!) == a.endIndex // true
```

From the documentation:

> A string’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.